# How to get the super user in a functional test?

Tags: 8, testing

How can I get the information for the super user (uid 1) in a functional test?

I want to test the external auth logic I have written, and one of the steps is authenticating the Drupal superuser locally instead of in the remote system. I am not seeing a way to get the username/password of that user in order to simulate a login.

Test:

```
  /**
   * The superuser should not authenticate to Netforum.
   */
  public function testSuperUserUsesDrupalAuthentication() {
    $this->drupalGet('user/login');
    $edit = ['name' => $this->rootUser->getEmail(), 'pass' => $this->rootUser->pass_raw];
    $this->drupalPostForm(NULL, $edit, t('Log in'));

    $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $this->assertEquals(1, $user->id());
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Kevin, did you get a chance to try out my suggestion below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because the password is not set to start with.
You can give this a try:

```
// Load real user object from UserSession object.
$admin_account = User::load($this->rootUser->id());
// The password is empty.
$this->assertFalse($admin_account->pass_raw);
// Set the password and save the User.
$new_password = $this->randomString();
$admin_account->setPassword($new_password);
$admin_account->save();
// Set the pass_raw directly on the User.
$admin_account->pass_raw = $new_password;
$this->drupalLogin($admin_account);
```

This is for the `WebTestBase`, if you use the `BrowserTestBase`, you should use the following (pass_raw ≠ passRaw)

```
// Load real user object from UserSession object.
$admin_account = User::load($this->rootUser->id());
// The password is empty.
$this->assertFalse($admin_account->passRaw);
// Set the password and save the User.
$new_password = $this->randomString();
$admin_account->setPassword($new_password);
$admin_account->save();
// Set the passRaw directly on the User.
$admin_account->passRaw = $new_password;
$this->drupalLogin($admin_account);
```

Good luck!

**References**

The details regarding the passRaw/pass_raw setting on the User object are available here:

- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21simpletest%21src%21WebTestBase.php/function/WebTestBase%3A%3AdrupalLogin/8.2.x
- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21Tests%21BrowserTestBase.php/function/BrowserTestBase%3A%3AdrupalLogin/8.2.x

Answer (score 1):

Looking into `BrowserTestBase` I accidentally found `$this->rootUser->name` and `$this->rootUser->pass_raw` last week. These are being used in [`installParameters()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!tests!Drupal!Tests!BrowserTestBase.php/function/BrowserTestBase%3A%3AinstallParameters/8.2.x). I have not tested it, but I suppose you should be able to use those in other functions as well.

rootUser appears to be a full AccountInterface object, so getName() and other methods should work as well..

Comment: Gotcha, I updated my question with the test after you provided that information. It is returning 0, instead of 1. Am I getting the user wrong?

Comment: I am not sure, I did not dig that deep. You can compare `\Drupal::currentUser()` after `$this->drupalLogin($this->rootUser);`. I'd expect it to be 1 though....

Comment: For some reason drupalLogin fails because it can't find the "User %user successfully logged in." message on the page. So I use drupalPostForm, to simulate a log in

Comment: But if you get user 0... That is the anonymous user. I get the idea your user is not getting logged in. (Bad credentials?) What if you use the name instead of the email address?

Comment: I am enforcing the email address, as that is what the remote system requires. My module has amended the login form to reflect that (but I did not change the form field key of "name"). It works when I do it manually, I just want to automate it.

Comment: Hard to tell. Your test also loads the required modules and configurations etc. for that to work? Can you validate that the form had indeed been altered in your test?

Comment: Yep. I am only requiring user, node, and my custom module. The setUp method configures the connection settings. But even in this case, that wouldn't so much matter, as the UserAuth service has the exemption for user 1 (I do a user lookup and check the password, if true and account id is one, it goes no further).

Comment: I just checked, but `$this->rootUser->id()` returns 1 as expected. If you get 0, I conclude that your login has failed. But I don't see what else I can do to help you with this... Good luck :)

Comment: Even $this->loggedInUser says FALSE. Odd.

Comment: Oh my god. I am overthinking it. I am not even passing a path to drupalPostForm! But I also see that you are supposed to use drupalLogin... I don't think that works in my case.